# Tensorflow / Keras: way to replace 3D Convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

For some research work, we applied some 3D-Conv layers from keras.

To test the trained model our mobile platform, the NVIDIA Drive PX2, we have to convert the model to TensorRT. However, currently 3D-Conv layers are not supported. Is there a way to replace the 3D-Conv layer with 2D or 1D convolutions? Retraining the model would be possible.